# How to make uniqueness check for email on contact object

Tags: contact, bulk-api

We are ISV and using Bulk API we are creating contact objects. However we want to ensure if contact with a given email exist, it should be updated rahter than creating duplicate contact object with same email.

Cutrrently we are using extenalId - this is unique id of contact-like object on external (external to SF) system.

Is there way we can make this uniqueness check on email on standard object ?

Comment: Yes you can use duplicate rules on Contact emails and set it to restrict.

Comment: We are ISV so might not be be possible to set this on Org which is using our package.

Comment: Create a field On Contact UniqueEmail...  In before trigger copy Email field to UniqueEmail, if the value exits your trigger will throw exception

Comment: Create Text field which is type of ExternalId and compare Externalid to prevent this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upsert against the Email field on Contact, but you'll still get an exception if you there already happens to be more than one Email that matches. You can do this in any API that accepts upsert, including Bulk, REST, and SOAP APIs. To restrict duplicate values, you'd have to write a trigger, but this only means that you're going to necessarily generate *errors* instead of mimicking upsert logic if you try that.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox . What do you mean upsert against Email? How do I tell bulk API to use email as matching field to create/update?

Comment: @AshishGaonker You specify the field when creating the job. [Bulk API 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/walkthrough_upsert.htm) has an example, and it's similar in the classic one, too (externalIdFieldName).

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. We are already using externalIdFieldName as another fields (which is unique guid on exernal system). I think we can have only one externalIdFieldName right. That mean we will have to replace external-guid with email ..